# download link for smpp client api for smpp 3.4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sms

Plese provide a smpp client that can be used for my mvc3 app. My sms provider is using smpp protocol 3.4 and i need a free client api for this. form where i can download same and use .

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest the following as starting points:

- [Jamaa SMPP Client](http://jamaasmpp.codeplex.com)
- [SMSC client .NET](http://www.tops.com.pl/en/products/smscc/index.html)
- [Inetlab.SMPP](http://www.inetlab.com)
- [SMPP Component [IP*Works! V8]](http://www.nsoftware.com/products/component/smpp.aspx)
- [ActiveXperts Mobile Messaging Toolkit](http://www.activexperts.com/mobile-messaging-component/)

Also see [A robust SMPP library for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820560/a-robust-smpp-library-for-net) which references [roaminsmpp](http://ostatic.org/roaminsmpp) and
[Easy SMPP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easysmpp/). However, the answer mentions these have issues, recommends ActiveXperts, but ultimately ended up writing their own.

Comment: i tried jamma smpp and inetlab but doesnt seems to meet my requirements. jamma is aking different parameters which is not able to provide from my part. also the main purpose of using this client api is for delivery report of sms send. i need a report from provider. the format for sending a sms is below                                                                http://addreess/?user=username&password=password&from=from&shortcode=&code&message=message&trasid=transid .so just specify a smpp client where i can pass url with these parameters.

Comment: I've added two more commercial clients to my list which support delivery reports, but I am struggling to find a free one. Who is your provider?

Comment: for example Opensmpp is a free one but i am not able to implement the same in my mvc3 project . its not made for a .net project

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I imagine you have looked at roaminsmpp and Easy SMTP (which I've just added above). They are both C# options, but I would be aware of the disclaimer from the original question I sourced them from. They appear to like ActiveXperts. It seems to be a case of "Good, Fast, Cheap. Pick Two" [^](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_triangle)