# as I can read a post by the SMPP protocol. NET C #

Tags: c#, smpp

I need to read a message via the SMPP protocol and save informacino in a database, as I can do this, I find much information to be sent, but I need specifically is capture by the C # language. NET if I can answer in SPANISH would be much better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to read SMS messages?

http://www.inetlab.com/Products/Inetlab.SMPP.aspx

http://sourceforge.net/projects/easysmpp/

[A robust SMPP library for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820560/a-robust-smpp-library-for-net)

http://www.tops.com.pl/en/products/smscc/index.html

Comment: Can you help me by using it in C # that I have no idea how to start using it.